# Python Webscraper Download PDF in Firefox

Tags: python, firefox, firefox-profile

I am programming a Python Webscraper which needs to be able to click on a download button and save a PDF to a location that is defined through an XML-File.

The problematic part of my code is the following:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

download_Path = items.get(key = 'dir') # Get download path from XML.

if not os.path.exists(download_Path):
    os.makedirs(download_Path)

profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
profile.set_preference("webdriver_enable_native_events", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/pdf;")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf;")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_Path)
profile.update_preferences()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = DriverPath, options = options, firefox_profile = profile)
```

Almost everything works fine, the download directory gets changed in the intended way, so the `profile.set_preferences` works, but the other preferences don't change. I'm searching for a while now and as you can see I tried different options so that the browser doesn't ask to open the file or where to save it, and just moves it in the given directory.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. The answere is, that you have to configure the PDF-Reader that is intergrated in Firefox ("PDF.js") separtly with the following code:

```
profile.set_preferences("pdfjs.disable", True)
```

That's it the rest functions as intended.